# Save dict as json using python in databricks

Tags: python, json, databricks, azure-data-lake

I am trying to save a dict as json in azure data lake/databricks however I am getting a File not found error. Any clue what I am doing wrong?

```
import json

test_config = {
  "expectations": [
    {
      "kwargs": {
        "column": "role",
        "value_set": [
          "BBV",
          "GEM"
        ]
      },
      "expectation_type": "expect_column_distinct_values_to_be_in_set",
      "meta": {}
    }]
    }

path = '/mnt/lake/enriched/checks/'
json_file = 'test_idm_expectations.json'

with open(path+json_file, "w") as fp:
    json.dump(test_config , fp)
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "/mnt/lake/enriched/checks/test_idm_expectations.json"
```

Variations of the path with `/dbfs/mnt/lake/enriched/checks/` or `dbfs:mnt/lake/enriched/checks/` also do not work.

Any help would be super appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is `/mnt/lake/enriched/checks/` the full path to that folder?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your python environment sees the mountpoint.
You can use `os.path.ismount` for that.
Also, check if the folder tree structure exists. `json.dumps` will create your file, but only if the folder exists.

Also, tip: to keep indentation, use `indent=2` or whatever number of spaces you want in your json, to be pretty printed.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced the above and got same error.

[image]

The above error occurs if we give wrong folder name in the path. you can see as there is no `sourcefolder1` in my container, it generated that error. It will not create new folder for us. It only creates that particular file(`mysample1.json` in this case).

You can see if I gave correct folder(which is created before) `sourcefolder` the file is generated successfully.

[image]

Give path like `/dbfs/mnt/folder/` only as I got same error when I gave path like `/mnt/folder/`.(`open()` not identifying paths in the mount might be the reason for it).

**File Generated:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Remzinho & @Rakesh, the folder structure was indeed not created. adding this snippet to my code before saving the data, solved the issue.

```
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.mkdir(path)

with open(path+json_file, "w") as fp:
    json.dump(test_config , fp)
```